# Need help making main background in CSS

Tags: css, background, program-entry-point

I want to create a gradient background just for the main background for every page. Whenever I do it I get the background, but it makes it the background for everything else (textbox, frames etc).

I just want it to be the main background. The colours are written below and I've pasted the code I'm using:

```
div  {
    background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(138, 223, 200), rgb(55, 35, 32));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use id or body tag css,

```
body{ background: ...... }
```

or use your background container css selector

div css selector will by default select  huge elements which rendered as

```
<div></div>
```

to apply your css background style.

Comment: use inline style on the element you want to style background and remove redundant css if you not sure how to do,which will avoid apply style to all divs.
such as <div id="main-bg" style="background: linear-gradient(to top, rgb(138, 223, 200), rgb(55, 35, 32));"></div>

Comment: Tried that as well, and it's not working. Just mentioned on the other reply that I'm using the Squarespace CSS editor. Could be helpful in resolving the issue?

Comment: normally for maximum compatibility purposes, i would recommend you use gradient image as background. which is also easy to implement than using css gradient bg color.  @ShafiChoudhury   
for css bg check if this helps you http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: I've given that site a go but no luck. I think what I might have to do is just create the gradient as an image and just upload it using the Squarespace background image uploader. I would have preferred the CSS option though.

Comment: browser compatibility issue? can u use chrome inspect element and see the css result that will help u solve the issue.